# How often can I rename discord channel's name?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

This is not a post about HOW to change channel's name (I know it).

I have an international server using several bots. And we all depend on UTC time (to coordinate through the world). So there was borned a solution to make a time-bot which will show current UTC-time in the dedicated channel nobody can visit. And yes, precision is necessary, even seconds.

I created a voice channel with permissions not to join for @everyone. Everything worked fine, it updated every 1000 ms. Then (after several months of good work) something was broke, it started updating incorrect. I've increased update interval up to 5000 ms and it have started to work fine... until yesterday.

Now it doesn't work anymore. Even if I increase interval much more. It works *sometimes* I don't really know what the interval is, it's huge and unpredictable.. the time-bot is broken for now and cannot be used anymore in that case.

Is there any restrictions for updating channel name? I can't find any information about this in available documentations.

```js
Client.setInterval(() => {
  const { h, m, s } = getTime();
  channel.edit({ name: `${getClockEmoji({ h, m })} UTC: ${h}-${m}-${s}` }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
}, updateInterval);
```

Providing data is correct, 'cause I send it to console and it updates as good as I need in interval I set. But channel name not updates that often..

Does discord filter too often update requests?

discord.js version is v.12.2.0

Answer (score 12):

Discord had set the rate limit for things like `channelrename` to **2 requests per 10 minutes.**
"Normal" requests like `sendmessage` is limited to 10,000 per 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to likely be an issue directly related to rate limiting:
https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits

> **IP addresses that make too many invalid HTTP requests are automatically and temporarily restricted from accessing the Discord API. Currently, this limit is 10,000 per 10 minutes. An invalid request is one that results in 401, 403, or 429 statuses.**
>
> For every API request made, we return optional HTTP response headers containing the rate limit encountered during your request.

You should probably decrease the interval by a considerable amount to reduce the risk of the IP being restricted.