# Discord bot can only change voice channel name twice (JS)

Tags: javascript, bots, discord

I'm trying to make a bot, where it automatically updates some voice channel names, so they'll work as statistics for a small game.

If I make a new voice channel, it works with that for two name changes, and then it won't change it anymore, no matter if I restart the bot. It's an issue, as this should continuously update it 24/7.

```
            if (message.channel.id === "718601383527317514") {
            message.guild.channels.get("718930156852477993").setName("SelfMade - " + infected + " Infected");
            message.channel.send("Updated!");
            }
```

'infected' is a variable I retrieve from a file, but I've tried removing that, so it changes the name of the voice channel to just a string, so I know it's not because of the variable.

**How do I fix this?**

Comment: Are there name changes appearing in the audit log on discord? Also, is there any errors related to rate limiting or anything else?

Comment: @Rodentman87 Yes, the first two name changes appear in the audit log, but then it just shows nothing, as the bot didn't even try to change it anymore. I can't see why it would be the bot's fault - why would it just stop changing the name after two times? Not sure if Discord has some kind of cooldown.

Comment: Are there any errors in the bot's log or anything? Also, is this function actually being called more than twice?

Comment: @Rodentman87 Nope, no errors or anything that might show a solution.
I mean, the bot is supposed to change the name of the server each time someone writes a specific message in a channel, and I've tried writing that message a lot of times with intervals in between as well, but no luck after exactly TWO changes.

Comment: Try adding a print statement in that if to check that the if is actually being run each time and there isn't some other issue.

Comment: @Rodentman87 It already logs in console and writes a messages on Discord after the name change event has happened, and both of those things work, just not the name change after two times.

Comment: This sounds like it's a rate limit issue, try slowing down the speed with which the channel name is updated.

Comment: @Rodentman87 Yeah, I figured that that might be the problem. The updates are random and depends on what the "players" in my game does, but I guess it's all good if the stats updates every x minutes, and not instantly.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting Rate - Limited because you can change a Channelname 2 times in under 10 minutes.

For more informations go:
[Here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits)

There get you information how to get more information about, how to avoid it.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62103163/how-often-can-i-rename-discord-channels-name)
( + own experience)